# Why dotnet build don't raise warnings?

Tags: c#, .net

here is example code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1_toDelete;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        File.WriteAllTextAsync("", null);
        var task = File.WriteAllTextAsync("", null);
        var b = doAsyncOperation();
    }

    public static async Task<bool> doAsyncOperation()
    {
        await Task.Delay(400);
        // do work
        return true;
    }
}
```

My question is why is raised warning at first line in MainAsync() but not at second and third...?

Result of dotnet build:

> Program.cs(12,9): warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
> Program.cs(10,23): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
> 2 Warning(s)
> 0 Error(s)

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Because the errorchecker is not perfect. It assumes you know what you are doing, because you explicitly assign the (currently not awaited) task to a variable. The error checker is not sophisticated enough to see, whether you do anything with that task. PS: in case you intentionally start a task without awaiting it use `_ = File.WriteAllTextAsync("", null);` to make the warning go away.